# Connection errors while moving solution from one environment to another through pipeline

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I'm currently working with three distinct environments: development, test, and production, and I've set up a pipeline to facilitate the smooth transition of our solutions across these environments.

In my development environment, I've created a Power App that is integrated with the development SQL Database. However, when I attempt to deploy this Power App to the test environment using the pipeline, I'm encountering connection errors.
[image: Connection Errors]

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community on how to overcome these connection issues during the deployment process. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**Steps Taken So Far:** Here's what I've already tried to resolve the issue:

- I've verified that I can establish a connection to the Azure SQL Database in both the development and test environments by creating test apps that use the connections I've created.
- I've ensured that all required objects are in place before initiating the deployment to the test environment.
  [image: Added Required Object]

**End Goal:** My ultimate objective is to seamlessly transition the database connection from the development SQL Database to the production SQL Database in our production environment. However, I'm currently stuck at the testing phase due to the connection errors.

Comment: Try this: first create necessary connections in the test environment and then deploy the solution from DEV to test environment.